# apple push notification not working for python

Tags: python, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

It seems to be working fine with my php script, but not my python script:

```
from APNSWrapper import *

wrapper = APNSNotificationWrapper('ck.pem', True)
for token in ['<Device token>']:
    token = binascii.unhexlify(token)
    apn = APNSNotification()
    apn.token(token)
    alert = APNSAlert()
    alert.body('ab sent you a message.')
    apn.appendProperty(APNSProperty('content', 'Yo'))
    apn.appendProperty(APNSProperty('path', 'chat/1236'))
    apn.alert(alert)
    apn.sound()
    wrapper.append(apn)
wrapper.notify()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pushnot.py", line 15, in <module>
    wrapper.notify()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/APNSWrapper/notifications.py", line 194, in notify
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 215, in connect
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 161, in connect
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 333, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 323, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

PHP script (Working):

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '<Device token>';


// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = '';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

It has just stopped working suddenly. Not sure why.

The PHP script is using the same pem file and device token.

Comment: May be your script can not find .pem file. Give physical path of .pem file any try once again.

Comment: how can i check if it cannot find the pem file? I have put both files in the same directory

Comment: @Sandeep I am using the same php code to send push notification on to iOs devices. On terminal it prints "Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered "  But not receiving any notification onto device. Please help.

Comment: Please following things are present on your device. 1. Device has app installed with same profile/ certificate that you used. 2. if app is running then check the push notification received delegate method and print it on log. 3. if app is in kill state (not running ) then check system notification tray 4. check same Push notification device token that you used 5. Check pay load keys are not wrong.   Let me know if you required more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiencing this same issue myself, I eventually found a fix that points out the root cause.

"Apple sandbox gateway stopped supporting SSL3."

https://bitbucket.org/sardarnl/apns-client/pull-request/10/apple-sandbox-gateway-stopped-supporting/diff

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the answer here that suggest to use comprehensive library PyAPNS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26290076/324490